# Node, TS, express and Socket.IO server crashes on heroku with code=H10

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, heroku, socket.io

I've hosted a node TS server on Heroku, and while the application functions perfectly, it crashes when I resume use after some time of inactivity. Below is the error code I see in the heroku logs.

at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O838TxJ" host=rgt-server.herokuapp.com request_id=640e7b4e-d679-4ffb-8811-dd369c338004 fwd="102.176.94.160" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by adding an error handler to my `redis` client.

```
// handle redis connection temporarily going down without app crashing
redisClient.on("error", function(err) {
  console.error("Error connecting to redis", err);
});
```